# regarding printing the shape of tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I test the following code script

```
import tensorflow as tf

a, b, c = 2, 3, 4
x = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([a, b, c], mean=0.0, stddev=1.0,    dtype=tf.float32))
s = tf.shape(x)
print(s)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
print(sess.run(s))
```

Running the code gets the following result

```
Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
[2 3 4]
```

Looks like only the second print gives the readable format. What does the first print really do or how to understand the first output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to [`s = tf.shape(x)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#shape) defines a symbolic (but very simple) TensorFlow computation that only executes when you call `sess.run(s)`.

When you execute `print(s)` Python will print everything that TensorFlow knows about the tensor `s` without actually evaluating it. Since it is the output of a [`tf.shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#shape) op, TensorFlow knows that it has type `tf.int32`, and TensorFlow can also infer that it is a vector of length 3 (because `x` is statically known to be a 3-D tensor from the variable definition).

Note that in many cases you can obtain more shape information without calling a tensor by printing the static shape of a particular tensor, using the [`Variable.get_shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable.get_shape) method (similar to its cousin [`Tensor.get_shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor.get_shape)):

```
# Print the statically known shape of `x`.
print(x.get_shape())
# ==> "(2, 3, 4)"
```